# How do I echo line breaks from a MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, echo

I have created a simple wall post feature, like on FaceBook.

A user writes a post, the post is submitted to the database and then echoed back onto the website; that all works.

The only issue is, when the text is echoed back onto the website the line break isn't. So, I typed:

> "Hey this is a post.
>
> Here is a new paragraph"

and it displayed as:

> "Hey this is a post. Here is a new paragraph"

I've seen a few posts here saying to use the nl2br() function and input /n for a new line, however I really don't want my users to have to write '/n' everytime they want a new line, they should just have to press the enter key on the keyboard.

The line break is stored in the database, so I have no idea why it isn't echoed out. Can anyone help?

Not sure if the code will be necessary but I'll post it just in case.

```
while($wallposts = mysql_fetch_assoc($getwallposts)) {
    $postid = $wallposts['id'];
    $postedby_username = $wallposts['postedby'];
    $wallpostdate = $wallposts['dateposted'];
    $wallpost = $wallposts['post'];

    $querypostedby_info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$postedby_username'");

    //get the info above
    if (mysql_num_rows($querypostedby_info)===1) {
        $getpostedby_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($querypostedby_info);

        $postedby_id = $getpostedby_info['id'];
        $postedby_profilepicture = $getpostedby_info['profilepicture'];
    }

    //display the posts
    $wallpoststicker = 
    "
    <div id='wallpost-container'>
        <div id='wallpost-header'>
            <img src='$postedby_profilepicture'><div id='wallpost-header-by'><a href='/profile.php?id=$postedby_id'>$postedby_username</a> said:</div>
            <div id='wallpost-date'>&bull; $wallpostdate</div> 
        </div>
        <div id='wallpost-content'>
            $wallpost
        </div>
    </div>
    ";
}
```

Comment: Try enclosing them in `<pre>` tags, like this: `...<div id='wallpost-content'><pre>{$wallpost}</pre></div>...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP function
    nl2br
converts newlines to "`<br>`" breaks.

So, `$wallpost=nl2br($wallpost);`
should accomplish the task.

Comment: This is what echoes when I put that: "Hey this is a post. Here is a new paragraph=nl2br(Hey this is a post. Here is a new paragraph);"

Comment: @Harry Forgive my failure to understand, so are you getting the desired newline-to-BR conversion (nl2br) or not?

Comment: @Harry I stand corrected. Please enclose the `$wallpost=nl2br($wallpost);` line in `<?php ... ?>` tags and "echo" out where necessary. Thank you.

Comment: So you want me to put "<?php $wallpost=nl2br($wallpost); ?>" inside the <div id='wallpost-content'>? I'll see if that works in a second, my server is down at the moment. :/

Comment: `<?php $wallpost=nl2br($wallpost); echo $wallpost; ?>"`

Comment: No text is being displayed at all now... hm?

Comment: Remember that, that portion of the HTML code is in a variable, I wasn't aware that you could put <?php ?> tags inside a variable.

Comment: My apologies! Can you please put the `$wallpost=nl2br($wallpost);` someplace above the `$walpoststicker=` ? <br> No, one cannot put a <?php tag inside a variable, I am sorry, I overlooked: something had tricked me into thinking this was a mix of HTML and PHP code. I was looking where did I lose 20 points and one comment.

Comment: Works! Thank you. I just discovered a new problem though, it's off topic but, only one post is returned, despite having two in the database. I have mistyped something here: $getwallposts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wallposts WHERE postedto='$profile_username' ORDER BY postid DESC LIMIT 3");

Comment: @Harry Well, if you kindly think I have deserved an "accepted answer", please accept this one dealing with your original question. 
It may be a good idea to open a new MySQL question to address the query part.
Thank you.

Comment: @Harry Don't use mysql_query, it's deprecated. Use mysqli_* functions and prepared statements. For the actual query, it will return up to 3 posts if 3 are present for the condition specified in your where clause. Tom's right though, should be a new question.

Comment: @Harry Thank you! If you still need help with MySQL query, please let me know. It's 5 a.m. my time, but I will stay up for a little.

Comment: I'm still having issues with it yes, and I can't post another question for another 90 minutes. I know that MySQL is deprecated however my PHP version is capable of handling mysql queries. I have no idea why only the first post 'postid 1' is being displayed when there are 3 posts in the database.

Comment: IDK, Skype, phone or any similar suggestion?

Comment: I didn't include the post query in the sample, the post query is $getwallposts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `wallposts` WHERE `postedto`='Harry' ORDER BY `postid` DESC LIMIT 3;") or die(mysql_error()); and it is located just above the 'while' statement in my sample. I have changed the code you just selected to if (mysql_num_rows($querypostedby_info) > 0) and nothing has changed. That code simply gets some information from a different table.

Comment: Ah, the postedto should say '$profile_username' I was just debugging, with no luck. Even when I type in the profile name it still only displays one.

Comment: $postid = $wallposts['id']; has also been changed to $postid = $wallposts['postid'];

Comment: We may need to change the structure of the topmost while loop ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php ). However, ideally, can you install mysqli? I don't even have mysql_ anywhere to test/debug against.

Comment: What needs to be changed exactly?

Comment: Uninstall **php_mysql** an install **php_mysqli**. That will be a solid future investment.

Comment: I think I found the culprit.`$querypostedby_info = mysql_query` breaks the upper "while **mysql_fetch_assoc** " loop. Please move that `$querypostedby_info = mysql_query` outside the main "while" loop. Thank you.

Comment: Even when I completely remove that I still only get 1 result, and the variables within that query no longer work as they are defined in that loop.

Comment: What is your local time / how much more time do you have? I would load your code into my IDE to debug, although frankly, it's already 6:05 AM my time (smile) - but I have promised to also help you with the MySQL part.
What happens if you run `while($wallposts = mysql_fetch_assoc($getwallposts)) { print_r($wallposts);}` ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer(s) suggesting nl2br are great, I would go with that approach.

In your original question I think there is some confusion -- users don't type `\n` every time they want a new line. The slash is for escaping (special character, not a normal n).

On Windows machines, the Enter key is equivalent to `\r\n` where `\r` is carriage return and `\n` is new line. On Linux or similar, the Enter key is `\n`. `\r`'s ascii value is 13 and `\n`'s is 10.

So an EOL (End of Line) will either be `\r\n` or `\n`. Php has the `nl2br` function whose purpose is to replace all `\r\n` or `\n` with `<br>`, the html tag for a line break.